# How to use Haproxy sticky session ignoring client IP?

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy, sticky-session

I am using haproxy as load balancer for 3 application servers and before client traffic reached this load balancer, it will first hit a WAF which the WAF has multiple random distributed IPs. So as the connection renew, the original session could jump to another server due to changes of session cookies which I do not want that to happen.

The WAF vendor had advised me to either set the load-balancer's session Identifier to use X-Real-IP when making session cookies. Or delete IP combination from the identification for making session cookies which I do not know how to do so. Can advise me on this?

Below is my haproxy setting.

```
frontend http_frontend
bind *:80
acl url_static       path_beg       -i /static /images /javascript /stylesheets
acl url_static       path_end       -i .jpg .gif .png .css .js

use_backend static          if url_static
default_backend bk_http

frontend https_frontend
bind *:443
mode tcp
default_backend bk_https

backend static
balance     roundrobin
server      static 127.0.0.1:4331 check

backend bk_http
mode http
balance     roundrobin
stick on src table bk_https
cookie SRVNAME insert
server  web1 ip1:80 check cookie SA check
server  web2 ip2:80 check cookie SB check

backend bk_https
mode tcp
balance leastconn
stick-table type ip size 2000k expire 30m
stick on src
default-server inter 1s
cookie SRVNAME insert
server  web1 ip1:443 check cookie web1
server  web2 ip2:443 check cookie web2
```

Answer (score 3):

I think cookie is available only in http mode, in TCP mode you need to do ssl affinity

Try this :

```
#maximum SSL session ID length is 32 bytes.
stick-table type binary len 32 size 20M expire 30m
acl clienthello req_ssl_hello_type 1
acl serverhello rep_ssl_hello_type 2

# use tcp content accepts to detects ssl client and server hello.
tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
tcp-request content accept if clienthello

# no timeout on response inspect delay by default.
tcp-response content accept if serverhello

# SSL session ID (SSLID) may be present on a client or server hello.
# Its length is coded on 1 byte at offset 43 and its value starts
# at offset 44.
# Match and learn on request if client hello.
stick on payload_lv(43,1) if clienthello

# Learn on response if server hello.
stick store-response payload_lv(43,1) if serverhello
server XXX:443 check
server YYY:443 check
option ssl-hello-chk
```

For check that, enable stats by socket and connect 2 browsers on site by haproxy :

```
stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats


bash#> echo "show table" | socat unix-connect:/var/lib/haproxy/stats stdio
# table: BACKEND_NAME, type: binary, size:20971520, used:2

bash#>echo "show table BACKEND_NAME" | socat unix-connect:/var/lib/haproxy/stats stdio
# table: BACKEND_NAME, type: binary, size:20971520, used:2
0x7f9ca0f24314:
key=8A3DF855010388A4DD94F71E0FEAF7A54A7032EA56D477D20F59B4F28CEF183B use=0
exp=1264499 server_id=1
0x7f9ca0f245c4:
key=C7EA05BA85730EAF725035EFB3C4F7537FCCCFD0469FB45A4A2DE85308ECF1C7 use=0
exp=1696667 server_id=2
```

Warning, if you have nbproc enable, affinity is limited on process.